# newbie: is it possible to wordpress theme with LAMP stack

Tags: wordpress, lamp

I created the site `http://staffmeup.com/`
We love the look of the home pages of some wordpress themes we've seen recently.

QUESTION: in theory, is it possible to use a wordpress theme as our home page at staffmeup.com, but then have all of the rest of the internal pages of the site run as it is currently built? (below, per my developer). If it is at least *possible*, are there any strong cautions or reasons not to do it?

1) The site is built using Zend Framework 2 on a traditional LAMP stack

2) Server is LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

3) We run PHP 5.3

Comment: anything is possible, your question is "how?"

Comment: It probably won't make sense to set up Wordpress just to have the front page look in a certain way. Anything a Wordpress theme can achieve, pure HTML and CSS can, too.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is possible, but it doesn't make any sense and integrating the two platforms would still require a developer and most likely would ultimately be more work (not to mention be a lot harder to update and maintain both from an admin perspective and a development perspective) than simply mimicking the design or functionality of one of the Wordpress theme home pages you like while staying in your current platform and framework.

In short, yes it's technically possible, but realistically it doesn't particularly make sense to do so. The only reason I can think you might want to use Wordpress for the home page and your own custom platform for the rest of the site is to avoid paying your developer for more hours to build the homepage on your platform, but integrating Wordpress with your existing site is going to take developer expertise anyway so that's a moot point.

It would make more sense to take the Wordpress theme's home page code (HTML/CSS/JS) and associated template(s) and adapt them to use whatever templating system (PHP) your site uses rather than Wordpress's templating system.

Comment: Exactly! ~~> "It would make more sense to take the Wordpress theme's home page code (HTML/CSS/JS) and associated template(s) and adapt them to use whatever templating system (PHP) your site uses rather than Wordpress's templating system."